# Craft 3 Upgrade having issues with rich text editor

Tags: craft3, redactor, richtext

I know that Craft3 now requires Redactor or CKEditor plugins to handle rich text editing, however after installing the Redactor plugin through the store, I am getting this error in the 'Body'.
The title and everything else works, just the body gets the error:

> Unable to find component class 'RedactorI'.

[image: error]

Simple.json

```
{
  "buttons": ["bold", "italic"]
}
```

Standard.json

```
{
  "formatting": ["h2","h3","h4","h5","p", "blockquote"],
  "buttons": ["html","formatting","alignment","bold","italic","unorderedlist","orderedlist","link","file","image","video","table"],
  "plugins": ["fullscreen","video","table"],
  "toolbarFixed": true
}
```

I've checked my craft/config/redactor simple and standard JSON files and they're properly formatted.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about `craft/config/redactor`? I ask because in Craft 3 the config is in `config/redactor`

Comment: Yeah it's in the right spot, I just meant my craft folder on the server. So it's still config/redactor, just inside of the overall craft folder.

Comment: Weird that the error msg is `Unable to find component class 'Redactorl'.` and not `Unable to find component class 'Redactor'.` What is 'l' doing there? Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: Hmm I think I figured out what went wrong. In the admin page settings, the field types were set to plain text and I got the same missing component class 'RedactorI'.
But I set the field type to Redactor and now my body and the rich text editor are working.

Comment: @RickyPeters Would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by installing the Redactor plugin, going through admin/settings/fields on the admin page and changing the field types dropdown from Plain Text to Redactor.

[image]